# Any way to set a horizontally repeated background image to position: fixed?

Tags: css

I have a menu at the top of the page which is fixed in place using position: fixed. Our background creates a thin horizontal line that is just underneath the menu. Currently, as the page content is scrolled the background scrolls with it. As a result, the line moves up with the content. I have looked for a way to fix the background in place so this doesn't happen. I have only found css to hold the background in place where the image is not repeated. Is there any way to fix the vertical position of a background image that is repeated horizontally?

my current background:

```
.backg { background: url(../images/background.gif) 0 0 repeat-x !important;
```

all layout views:

```
<body class="backg">
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: Went with the solution Tim suggested below: "adding the background styling to your fixed menu div, then it will be fixed also." So i marked his answer, but the real answer was in the comment below it.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not possible with css2 (don't know with css3), but you can still create an image with empty space as your _fixed height_ and repeat it over the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line will repeat your image horizontally, 100px from the top of the container:

`.backg { background: url(../images/background.gif) 0 100px repeat-x !important;`

Comment: @TimS, i probably was not clear enough. I need it fixed when the page scrolls over it. Currently the background scrolls with the content and so the way the background frames our menu passes over top of the menu when the page is scrolled. Thanks.

Comment: add `px` chars after `100`, or it won't do

Comment: @Jay sorry still not sure I'm with you. Are you using position: fixed?

Comment: @TimS, i clarified my question... i hope :=]

Comment: @Jay ok thanks for that, is .backg within your position:fixed container?

Comment: @TimS, updated question above. It is part of the body tag on all our layout views. e.g. <body class="backg">

Comment: @Jay ok, I'd suggest either going with Nacho's suggestion of some blank space in the image, or adding the background styling to your fixed menu div, then it will be fixed also.